# Why 'ios::operator !' and 'ios::operator void*' rather than 'ios::operator bool'?

Tags: c++, boolean, operator-overloading, type-conversion, iostream

The C++ standard I/O stream class `ios` defines two overloaded operator `!` and `void*` that are used to check the stream's state.

For example:

```
ifstream fin("hello.txt");
if (fin)  {} // ios::operator void*() is called
if (!fin) {} // ios::operator !() is called
```

However, I think two overloaded operators are overdid. Why not just one overloaded function `operator bool()`?

It is likely because I/O stream classes were widely used before `bool` became one of C++ keywords. In other words, keep them there just for backward compatibility.

If just for backward compatibility, why are they not marked as deprecated? If not for backward compatibility, then for what?

Comment: It's more likely to be the safe bool idiom. If there was an operator bool, you could assign an ifstream to any numeric type. The safe bool idiom is obsolete in C++11 because you can make `operator bool` explicit.

Comment: Thanks to Pseudonym. Your link is very useful.

Comment: It's more than deprecated, `basic_ios::operator void*` isn't even part of C++ anymore (as of C++11)

Comment: @Pseudonym - `operator void*()` is one of the poster children that the "safe bool" proponents point to as a justification for their paranoia. Just think, you might accidentally write `delete std::cout;` and it would compile and run!

Comment: @Pete Becker - There are varying levels of safe bool proponents. I used it for things that a programmer could actually confuse for numbers. Think of big integers, for example. You would certainly like to test if a big integer is nonzero with `if (n)`, but you certainly don't want that implicitly converted to an integer, because that would mean something different.

Comment: @Pseudonym - for a large integer type, a conversion to `void*` avoids conversion to an integer.

Comment: I know. I was talking about a non-explicit conversion to bool, which would have been inappropriate in that case.

Comment: The whole premise of this question, as written in 2013, is wrong.  The C++ standard does not define `operator void*` for streams. (An earlier version did...)